# Performing XSL Transformation in VSTS

Tags: xslt, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As part of a build definition in VSTS I'm using a tool that produces an xml report.

To make the report easier to consume I'd like to perform an XSL transformation to produce an HTML version.

Is there a build step that can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using this NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReSharperReports/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Powershell Task with similar inline code:

```
 $Xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
 $Xslt.Load($PathToXsltFile)
 $Xslt.Transform($PathToXmlSourceFile, $PathOfOutputFile)
```