# How to perform XSLT on XML file in VSTS (Azure DevOps) using Saxon?

Tags: xml, xslt, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, saxon

I am working in Visual Studio Team Services (now Azure DevOps). I am running PHPUnit and exporting test results as JUnit for VSTS to consume; however, I receive an error when attempting to run the PublishTestResults task with the PHPUnit XML file:

```
"##[warning]Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/styled-results.xml' matches 'JUnit' test results format."
```

So after a long time researching the problem, I found one other person attempting to publish a PHPUnit generated JUnit file to VSTS [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17985361-include-support-for-phpunit-test-results-and-code). It turns out that they simply don't support the output of PHPUnit. [A community member has posted this gist](https://gist.github.com/cooperaj/257032b6db68dd2ba6872baca3ad0cb5) of an XSL file to transform the XML into a format that VSTS (Azure DevOps) will understand.

The creator of the gist mentioned that he used saxonb in a script task on VSTS to process the XSLT. I have no idea how to run saxonb on VSTS. I don't know the name of the executable to call, the options, etc. I tried the Saxon docs, but I can't seem to get this working on a VSTS Ubuntu 16.04 build agent.

I should also note that I tried [performing the XSL transform via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153616/performing-xsl-transformation-in-vsts) with no success.

Comment: So what kind of OS is that you have access to run Saxon, is that a Windows system with .NET framework 4 or later? Then you can install the .NET version of Saxon 9.8 HE from https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.8/ and run it as documented (`Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl`) at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/. If you have Java installed or can install it then you can use the Java version of Saxon 9.8 HE.

Comment: No idea why you are asking about the ancient Saxon-B, it is available  at https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/, documentation is linked for download from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I mentioned that I am running this on an Ubuntu 16.04 build agent above. I am asking about Saxon-B because that's what the OP of the fix said he used, before 8am this morning I had no idea what Saxon even was. I am currently trying to run the JAR file of Saxon 9 HE on my build agent by adding the JAR to my repo. Thanks for the help and the links.

Comment: Yes, I saw that with Ubuntu, but as you also mentioned PowerShell I was not sure and still are not whether Windows tools or the .NET framework are available. But I guess the Java version of Saxon will do.

Comment: Yes PowerShell is available, as I'm running on a Microsoft hosted build agent. I ended up getting everything working by adding the jar to my repository and executing that jar once the tests are run. Afterwards I dump the entire dir containing the jar and the test results so they don't get pushed to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to download the Java version of Saxon 9 HE as a JAR and run that JAR in VSTS (Azure DevOps). I am running on a hosted Ubuntu 16.04 build agent (which comes with Java, PHP, etc. installed already).

I executed the jar simply by executing the java binary and passing my JAR in the same location as my XML and XSL file:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:phpunit_to_junit.xsl -s:test-results.xml
```

This generated a folder that contained my tests, properly formatted for VSTS (Azure DevOps) to consume. Your set up will differ, as all of my tests have '-Test.xml', check out the testResultsFiles option.

I set up my tests to output with the '-Test.xml' by modifying the following line in the XSL.

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('TEST-',@name,'-Test.xml')" />
```

The next step was to publish my tests using the PublishTestResults task. This is what my YAML file contains for publishing the results.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
  inputs:
    testRunner: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*-Test.xml' 
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    mergeTestResults: false
```

Comment: For an example you can see it in here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8305